# Django, why doesn't it post to db?

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

So I made dependent dropdown menu but it won't post to database. What am I doing wrong?

Also, is it possible to post this to different table? The thing is, I have 5 of same form on same page each with their on OrderForm, Model Like this named 1 through 5. But it wouldn't post whether I use 1 form per page or 5 forms on same page. I would prefer if there is a way to use raw sql and insert these form data into different table mapping fields to specific fields.

models.py

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):

    vendor_name = models.ForeignKey(Vendor, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    menu_name = models.ForeignKey(Menu, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField('date created', auto_now_add=True)
    note = models.CharField('note', max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
    class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
        note= forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    
        class Meta:
            model = OrderItem
            fields = ('vendor_name', 'menu_name', 'note')
    
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['menu_name'].queryset = Menu.objects.none()
    
            self.fields['vendor_name'].widget.attrs['style'] = 'width:250px; height:25px;'
            self.fields['menu_name'].widget.attrs['style']  = 'width:250px; height:25px;'
            self.fields['note'].widget.attrs['style']  = 'width:250px; height:100px; resize:none;'
```

views.py

```
def save_order(request):
    form = OrderForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    return render(request, '/order_info.html', {'form': form})
```

order_info.html

```
<div class="">
          <form method="post" id="order_Form2" class="form2" menus-url="{% url 'ajax_load_menus' %}">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            {% bootstrap_button 'Pick' button_type='submit' button_class='btn-primary btn-sm mb-2'%}
            <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm ml-2 mb-2" href="{% url 'order-page' %}">Reset</a>
          </form>

          <script>
            $("#order_Form2 #id_vendor_name").change(function () {
              var url = $("#order_Form2").attr("menus-url");
              var vendorId = $(this).val();

              $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: {
                  'vendor_name': vendorId
                },
                success: function (data) {
                  $("#order_Form2 #id_menu_name").html(data);
                }
              });
            });
          </script>
        </div>
```

load_menu.html

```
<option value="">---------</option>
{% for menu in menus %}
<option value="{{ menu.pk }}">{{ menu.menu_name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

url.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("order_info", views.OrderView, name="order-page"),
    path('ajax/load_menus/', views.load_menus, name='ajax_load_menus'), # AJAX\
    path('/', views.save_order, name="save_order"),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your django code looks good. I think the issue you still have to add "type" in jquery:

```
      $.ajax({
            // ADD "type"
            type:'POST'
            url: url,
            data: {
              'vendor_name': vendorId
            },
            success: function (data) {
              $("#order_Form2 #id_menu_name").html(data);
            }
          });
```

Comment: If I put type: 'POST' there, I get Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.) error and dependent dropdown doesn't work. :(

Comment: Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /ajax/load_menus/  to be exact for error message.

Comment: @DC add thsi "headers: {
                "X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken")
            }," $.ajax({ })

Comment: tried that as well as const csrftoken = Cookies.get('csrftoken'). they just remove the error message but they don't post to db. :(

Comment: could it be postgres setting in setting.py? but if it was that, my user creation page or posting from admin page shouldn't work either, right? -_-;

Comment: got it to work. the issue was in view. i removed save_order view and merged that save form code to order-info page. it made it work. :(

Comment: also validation issues with __init__.. damn.. this issue took me all day today

Comment: @DC feel lucky you solved your issue in a day :)